# Has anyone considered making a Dragonlance motion picture?

Tags: movie, dragonlance

Has anyone considered making a *Dragonlance* movie? Even just the original  *Chronicles* and *Legends* trilogies could yield six very good films.

Comment: I edited out the last sentence of your question, since it was opinion-based and not objectively answerable. The rest may or may not be answerable; we'll have to wait and see.

Comment: @Brad I would love to see the Corean Chronicles made into a movie/s. Doubt it will happen but...

Comment: You have edited your question, invalidating the current answers. But the current answers were perfecty valid before your edit. Your edit makes the current answers seem bad. This type of editing is not considered good here, because it adversely affects the people who went through efforts to (correctly) answer your question.

Comment: I've rolled back your last edit which invalidated the answers you were given. As @Fiksdal explained, this is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks to the edit of @Null ,I've removed my downvote now.

Answer (score 16):

They *did* make a Dragonlance film in 2008, named [Dragonlance: Dragons of Autumn Twilight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonlance:_Dragons_of_Autumn_Twilight) and based on the novel of the same name.

It was [dire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0825245/reviews?ref_=tt_ov_rt), lost pots of money even on its tiny $1.5m budget (it ended up going straight-to-video) and basically killed any hopes of an animated franchise. There were suggestions of a sequel, but it seems to have been stuck in development hell since at least 2011.

---

As to why it's not been made into a big-budget franchise, the reality is that [the company that owns the rights to the novels](http://www.trhickman.com/qa-owns-dragonlance/) has historically been very risk-averse. Like Nintendo, they seem to have decided that the risk of damaging their IP by making them into a film that tanks is worth less money to them than simply leaving them as books. I would imagine that their animated toe-in-the-water and seeing how another couple of theatrical films set in basically the same universe ([Eragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eragon) and [Dungeons and Dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_(film))) have fared at the box office (hint, both flopped **hard**) has probably convinced them that their strategy is the right one, at least for the time being.

Comment: Presently available on Youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0reHLHGyQnM

Comment: Ah... you beat me to it *as* I was writing....:p

Comment: There was an old animated Lord of The Rings movie too but that was eventually made into a proper film. Dragonlance would be ideal given the scale of the universe but probably just the first 6 books...or at the very least just the original Chronicles trilogy.

Comment: @Brad You are not the only one that thinks that - http://io9.gizmodo.com/why-dragonlance-should-be-the-next-fantasy-film-franchi-1520791414

Comment: Poor Tanis Half-elven... whether due to animation errors or an overly literal artist, he literally had one elf ear and one human ear.

Comment: @Brad Animated movies are films to, don't be animist!

Comment: I have to correct you though @valorum eragon and dungeons and dragons are NOT set in the same universe as dragonlance (different universes compltely). That aside one thing that is also seen with eragon at least......films have the tendency to NOT adhere at all to books in many important parts (eragon, percy jackson,...) and then the production studios and the ip holders are baffled why the books get superb money for them but the films fail,......

Comment: @Thomas - Much the same universe, with the same rules and based on books that had their genesis in the D&D gamespace.

Comment: @Valorum it is the same rules but the universe (thus what worlds, gods,...) exist are completely different. Especially for eragon which is not even based on d&d at all. The other two yes are baesd upon the same game SYSTEM but the universe is compltely different

Comment: @Thomas While the original works may be quite distinct, in my opinion, the films are all pretty generic fantasy.  I assume that's what Valorum was referring to.

Comment: The D&D movie may have flopped, but it DID spawn 2 sequels...

Comment: @MyCodeSucks - Yes, with less than a quarter of the budget of the original.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks - What sequels?

Comment: @Mazura: [D&D 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0406728/?ref_=nv_sr_3), even has Damodar from the first movie, [D&D 3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1733125/?ref_=nv_sr_2). There's also rumor of another [in development](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2906216/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3).

Comment: Looks like there might be a new one soon. https://twitter.com/JoeManganiello/status/850375707012120578

Comment: @JAB - Actors and producers get sent lots of scripts :-)

Comment: @Valorum He appears to actually be in talks to make this work. he's had meetings with WoTC(content owners), and even had a hand in writing the screenplay. This could be future awesome.

Comment: Whoever you are that gave this answer was correct on mostly everything but the budget. I know you quoted the budget in pounds but that doesn't come close to translating to the actual $50 million USD budget.

Comment: @Greegan - Dragonlance didn't have a $50m budget :-) According to http://www.dragonlancemovie.com, they had a micro-budget of a few million at most.

Comment: This was made in 2008? It looks like an 80's He-Man style cartoon. Looks very dated. I'm guessing this is one of the main reasons it flopped.

Comment: This makes me sad

Comment: Neither Eragon nor even *Dungeons and Dragons* are set in the same universe, though? Well, not really.

Comment: Dungeon and Dragons the roleplaying game is a set of rules that has several settings that a DM can use for example  The Forgotten Realms, Greyhawk, Ebberon, Dark Sun, Ravenloft and Dragonlance are settings that can be used. The choice of which setting a campaign takes places in is up to the GM and his players. Eragon is a High Fantasy novel but like many other high fantasy novels is not a D&D setting.

Comment: I dunno guys, I reread Dragonlance last year, it did NOT hold up, imo.  My memory of the quality of writing and story we're perhaps beset by nostalgia, but it was pretty bad by today's standards.  I think it'd have to be heavily rewritten to have any shot at being a decent film.

Comment: "Like Nintendo..." Too bad Nintendo didn't pause before that live-action Super Mario Bros. Movie. <shudder>

Answer (score 6):

It would seem that there already is a Dragonlance movie. Made in 2008 Dragonlance: Dragons of Autumn Twilight (animated) was directed by Will Meugniot, adapted for the screen by  George Strayton (*whose credits include "Cleopatria 2525", "Xena: Warrior Princess" and "Hercules: The Legendary Journeys"*), the film was produced by Toonz Animation, Commotion Pictures and Epic Level Entertainment, with conceptual artwork from Kunoichi and others. Paramount Pictures is looking after worldwide distribution.

It can be bought on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Y7U996)

Here is the trailer -

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHrOfJ8_D0o)

Some reviews - http://www.dlnexus.com/products/review/558.aspx

This is the [Official site](http://www.dragonlance-movie.com/movie/)

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is a much older question, but I was recently doing some investigation on the topic and found this article on the GeekAndSundry page: [What Joe Manganiello's Possible Dragonlance Movie Might Contain](https://geekandsundry.com/delving-into-a-possible-dragonlance-movie/).

> It’s recently come to light that actor Joe Manganiello has been
>   coauthoring a script for a Dungeons & Dragons movie. Speaking on the
>   Happy Sad Confused podcast, he said that he’d even met with Wizards of
>   the Coast to talk about the project. This was at first confusing news,
>   since it’s known that a D&D film is already in the works after a
>   prolonged legal battle pertaining to the game’s film rights.
>
> However Manganiello soon tweeted out a picture of a script draft,
>   indicating that the prospective movie would be an adaption of Margaret
>   Weis and Tracy Hickman’s beloved Dragon’s of Autumn Twilight.

This is still only a rumor at this point, and may not ever actually come to fruition, but the article links to a tweet from Mr. Manganiello in April of 2017 that apparently shows the cover page for a "Dragons of Autumn Twilight" screenplay by John Cassel.  If the rumor is true, it could lead to a more full-fledged production of the movie and, if the first one goes well, potentially a series.